# Wordpress - proper way to restrict access on management page by IP

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for the proper way of restricting access essentially to the management page of wordpress by IP.

Looking around, a solution i often see is using .htaccess. Even though not too bad for a solution, it doesn't look right plus it misses some actions that could be taken through xmlrpc.

There is also one plugin called "Secure Admin IP" which looks like is up for the job but it doesn't have a good number of installation.

Wordfence which is quite popular waf for wordpress doesn't seem to support this functionality. Does anyone have any suggestions for this issue? Is it something people don't frequently do, that's why there are not so many resources around it?

Also i am quite new to wordpress, so hopefully i haven't missed something very profound.

Comment: If you want to deny, at the server level, access to the admin, then you'll want a server-level control such as `.htaccess`. This is your best best to guarantee that code isn't allowed to run. Otherwise, Wordfence does a really great job of rate-limiting, country blocking and supports whitelisting of IP addresses. They also have an option to check passwords against known data-breaches and most importantly, they have alerts and logging. And if you're really paranoid, require MFA on all of your accounts.

Comment: i could be wrong, but i am with the impression that even if you whitelist an IP, wordfence would still allow a different IP to login (but that IP would have the other restrictions configured over wordfence, like captcha, rate limiting).

Comment: That is correct, whitelisting only stops additional checks for that IP, it doesn't make WordPress exclusive to it only. I don't know the rule order, but if the whitelist happens before the blacklist, you could conceivably blacklist the entire internet and then whitelist your subset, however you'd definitely want to test that first. But if you're really concerned about security, you really don't want code to run and the database to be involved, so I'd still recommend the htaccess method in that case.

Comment: I find it very mind boggling that such  a simple feature is not more readily available over wordpress. It's as simple as adding a simple hook into the login function and check that the login is performed by a given set of ips. Very simple very valuable. the .htaccess is very dirty solution and difficult to use and easy to screw up if not carefull (e.g. xmlrpc)

Comment: There's probably a bunch of plugins out there that do exactly what you're talking about, I just don't personally know about them. Instead, whenever something that is as you pointed out, mind boggling simple, many of us just hook into WordPress's native functionality with a couple lines of code. In this case, a simple hook into `login_init` should suffice. Depending upon your setup, finding the client's IP might be easy, but, if you've got a proxy in place you'll need to check a bunch of headers. Although a plugin _could_ do all of this, the code for it would be 100x more than the actual logic.

Comment: Also, your situation might require XML-RPC, but we actually used to disable that on most sites for security reasons, and it very rarely breaks things. A lot of (good and modern) code has been moved to the REST API so it isn't really an issue.